# Query two columns into one?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to select these two colums:

```
Name 1    |      Name 2
John             Paul
Paul             Ringo
Ringo            George
```

So as to get both in one column with no repeated values:

```
Names
John
Paul
Ringo
George
```

Comment: Please remember to accept answers to your questions - Over 60% of your most recent questions have not had answers accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT name1 FROM theTable
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT name2 FROM theTable
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you can use:

```
SELECT Name1 FROM Table1
UNION SELECT Name2 FROM Table1
```

That will perform duplicate row removal by default, or you can make it explicit like this:

```
SELECT Name1 FROM Table1
UNION DISTINCT SELECT Name2 FROM Table1
```

See the [docs for UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL supports the UNION command. You just need to make sure the columns returned are the same.

E.g.

```
SELECT customerNumber id, contactLastname name
FROM customers
UNION
SELECT employeeNumber id,firstname name
FROM employees
```